# One-to-one relationship between two tables. How to get foreign key from input form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, asp.net-core-mvc, one-to-one

I have problem with one-to-one relationship between two tables. I don't know how to link two input forms, where one form is tied to one table and the other form the other.Each form has its own View and own Controller. Please give me some advice or solution.

This is my first model Student:

```
namespace Sport_student.Models
{
    public class student
    {


        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Šifra ispitanika:")]
        [Range(1, 9999)]
        public int StudentNumber { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> Genders { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum rođenja ispitanika:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mjesto rođenja ispitanika:")]
        public string PlaceBirth { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> Classes { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum testiranja ispitanika:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Godina rođenja majke:")]
        [Range(1900, 2000)]
        public int MumDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Godina rođenja oca:")]
        [Range(1900, 2000)]
        public int DadDate { get; set; }
        public string MumSport { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> MumSports { set; get; }
        public string DadSport { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> DadSports { set; get; }
        public string WhichSportMum { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> WhichSportMums { set; get; }
        public string WhichSportDad { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> WhichSportDads { set; get; }
        public string SportStudentPast { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> SportsStudentPast { set; get; }
        public string SportStudentWhat { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> SportsStudentWhat { set; get; }
        public string HowLong { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> HowLongs { set; get; }
        public string SameTime { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> SameTimes { set; get; }

        //proba
        [ForeignKey("MeasureId")]
        public int? MeasureId { get; set; }
        public virtual Measures Measures { get; set; }

    }


}
```

This is my second model:

```
namespace Sport_student.Models
{
    public class Measures
    {


        [Key]
        public int MeasureId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Visina:")]
        public decimal Visina { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Težina:")]
        public decimal Tezina { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Skok u dalj:")]
        public decimal Sdaljmj { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dvamet:")]
        public decimal Dvamet { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Japan:")]
        public decimal Japan { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Kus:")]
        public decimal Kus { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Pretkorak:")]
        public decimal Pretk { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Čučnjevi:")]
        public decimal Cucnjevi { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Bacmed:")]
        public decimal Bacmed { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Ravklup:")]
        public decimal Ravklup { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Ravnasa:")]
        public decimal Ravnasa { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "BeepTest:")]
        public decimal BeepTest { get; set; }

        //proba
        public virtual student Student { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Controller for Student:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("StudentId,StudentNumber,Gender,DateBirth,PlaceBirth,Class,TestDate,MumDate,DadDate,MumSport,DadSport,WhichSportMum,WhichSportDad,SportStudentPast,SportStudentWhat,HowLong,SameTime,MeasureId")] student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _context.Add(student);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

Controller for Measures:

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> Create_M([Bind("MeasureId,Visina,Tezina,Sdaljmj,Dvamet,Japan,Kus,Pretk,Cucnjevi,Bacmed,Ravklup,Ravnasa,BeepTest")] Measures measures)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //tu stala

                _context.Add(measures);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Create","Student");
            }
            return View(measures);
        }
```

View with input form for Student:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="MeasureId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StudentNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StudentNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StudentNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Spol:</label>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Genders)
                {
                    <input asp-for="Gender" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @item.Text
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateBirth" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PlaceBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PlaceBirth" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PlaceBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Razred:</label>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Classes)
                {
                    <input asp-for="Class" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @item.Text
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TestDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TestDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TestDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MumDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MumDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MumDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DadDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DadDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DadDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Bavljenje sportom majke:</label>
                <select asp-for="MumSport" asp-items="@(ViewBag.MumSports)">

                    <option>Odaberi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Bavljenje sportom oca:</label>
                <select asp-for="DadSport" asp-items="@(ViewBag.DadSports)">

                    <option>Odaberi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Kojim se sportom najviše bavila majka:</label>
                <select asp-for="WhichSportMum" asp-items="@(ViewBag.WhichSportMums)">

                    <option>Odaberi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Kojim se sportom najviše bavio otac:</label>
                <select asp-for="WhichSportDad" asp-items="@(ViewBag.WhichSportDads)">

                    <option>Odaberi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Je li se polaznik do sada bavio nekim sportom?</label>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.SportsStudentPast)
                {
                    <input asp-for="SportStudentPast" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @item.Text
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Kojim sportom se bavio</label>
                <select asp-for="SportStudentWhat" asp-items="@(ViewBag.SportsStudentWhat)">

                    <option>Odaberi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Koliko dugo?</label>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.HowLongs)
                {
                    <input asp-for="HowLong" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @item.Text
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ispitanik se:</label>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.SameTimes)
                {
                    <input asp-for="SameTime" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @item.Text
                }
            </div>
            <a href="~/Measures/Create_M">Create New</a>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Kreiraj" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

View with input form for Measures:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create_M">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Visina" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Visina" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Visina" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Tezina" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Tezina" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Tezina" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Sdaljmj" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Sdaljmj" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Sdaljmj" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dvamet" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Dvamet" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Dvamet" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Japan" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Japan" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Japan" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Kus" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Kus" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Kus" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Pretk" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Pretk" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Pretk" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Cucnjevi" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Cucnjevi" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Cucnjevi" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Bacmed" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Bacmed" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Bacmed" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Ravklup" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Ravklup" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Ravklup" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Ravnasa" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Ravnasa" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Ravnasa" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BeepTest" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BeepTest" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BeepTest" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*//@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.MeasureId);*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My tables (Student,Measures) in database are right, Student table has FK MeasureId. I really dont know how to connect two input forms from two different Views in two different Controllers.Please direct me in the right direction. Any advice is welcome.
Remark: The data from forms is properly filled in,but the foreign key in the Student table remains null

Comment: The way you have it is a 1 to 0 : 1. A student can have zero or one measure. A measure has to have a student. I suppose you could do it in 2 steps where you add the student, save, then redirect to measure. A better design might be to build a student ViewModel that has all the fields you need from both tables, then present your student view perhaps with a section or partial view for the measure, then persist it in your POST.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, but for the first solution i have to link foreign key MeasuresId in Student table with primary key MeasureId in Measures table, and i have no idea how to do it and where. In this case, when I press submit button,it redirects me to Measure View and Student post method fills the data in the table Student but it doesn t fill FK MeasureId(it has NULL value). After redirecting, Measure input form works, it fills data in Measures table and PK MeasureId gets value.

Comment: That sounds right. Are you expecting different behavior? After all, there is no Measure at the time you save Student. Now if you use a ViewModel you could create a Measure, attach it to a Student, then when you save EF will do the FK assignment for you.